# FFMPEG Mpeg-DASH what attributes options and flags do we need to make H264 playable .mpd universally playable

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, mpeg-dash, low-latency, dash.js

I want to encode from any source to a universally playable .mpd with h264 codec.

Here my command

```
/usr/bin/ffmpeg -re -i 1.webm -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast 
-tune zerolatency -c:a aac -ac 2 -strict -2 -crf 18 -profile:v baseline 
-maxrate 1000k -pix_fmt yuv420p -flags -global_header -streaming 1 
-use_template 1 -use_timeline 0 -seg_duration 2 -remove_at_exit 1 
-f dash index.mpd
```

but with dash.js the log says

```
dash.js videoCodec (video/mp4;codecs="avc1") is not supported.
```

**EXTRA NOTE: When using -c:v libx264 and output in HLS .m3u8 --> it's working in all browsers

HTML with dash.js

```
<script src="http://cdn.dashjs.org/latest/dash.all.min.js"></script>
    <center><video width="90%" height="600" id="videoPlayer" controls=""
    src="" playsinline="true" preload="metadata" ></video></center>
    <script>
    (function(){
        var url = "https://www.---domain--path-to.mpd";
        var player = dashjs.MediaPlayer().create();
        player.initialize(document.querySelector("#videoPlayer"), url, true);
player.updateSettings({
            streaming: {
                 lowLatencyEnabled: true, 
                 liveDelay: 4,
                 liveCatchup: {
                    minDrift: 0.02,
                    maxDrift: 0,
                    playbackRate: 0.5,
                    latencyThreshold: 60    
                  }
            }
        });
    })();     
    video = document.getElementById("videoPlayer");
    video.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", function(){ video.muted = true; video.play(); }, false);
    </script>
```

I do have "-c:v libx264" but why dash.js sees avc1... I know that h264 have avc1, but how to fix this. Is it fixing the ffmpeg command or changing the `player.initialize` in the javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`video/mp4;codecs="avc1"` isn't a valid codecstring - it's missing the profile, constraints and level that are required by the SourceBuffer for this bitstream type.

It's happening because you have `-flags -global_header` set. This is causing the codec extradata to be unset, which in turn means that the ffmpeg DASH manifest generator cannot generate the correct codecstring.

Remove `-flags -global_header` and it should work fine.